# Delegate method not being called inside if statement

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I've created a UNNotification object so I can call multiple notifications within my app.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)

class AlertNotifications : NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate  {
    weak var notifyDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func registerNotification() {
        // notification authorization code
    }

    private func scheduleNotification() {
        //notification scheduler code
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("calling completion")
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
}
```

On my ViewController where I'm trying to set up the notification, I'm forced to wrap the call inside of an if statement since my app has to be compatible for iOS 9 and 10.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let notify = AlertNotifications()
    notify.notifyDelegate = self

    notify.registerNotification()
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions

    print("never called delegate")
}
```

Unfortunately, doing it this way is not calling the delegate method that was created by `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in my `AlertNotification` class.  My assumption is the delegate is not getting set properly, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The instance of your `AlertNotifications` class that you're creating will get deallocated as soon as you exit your if statement.  Something needs to keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: any time I try to make a strong reference to AlertNotifications, Xcode requires me to put it into the if statement.